# Grauert type theorem for artinian bases

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, artinian

We have met the following Grauert's theorem, say in Hartshorne's book.

Let $\pi: \mathcal X\to B$ be a propre flat morphism with $B$ *reduced*. Let $\mathcal F$ be a locally free coherent sheaf over $\mathcal X$. If for any (closed) points $b\in B$, $\dim H^i(X_b,\mathcal F|_{X_b})$ is constant, then $R^i\pi_*\mathcal F$ is locally free over $B$ and satisfies the base change: $R^i\pi_*\mathcal F|_b\to H^i (X_b,\mathcal F|_b)$ is an isomorphism.

I am wondering if an infinitesimal version of this theorem is true, i.e., when the base is artinian (so not reduced in general). Precisely, let $B=\mathrm{Spec}A$ be a local artin scheme of finite type over $\mathbb C$, with $0\in B$ the point. Let $\pi: \mathcal X\to B$ be a propre flat morphism defined over $\mathbb C$. Let $\mathcal F$ be a locally free coherent sheaf over $\mathcal X$. If we assume that the dimension of $H^I(\mathcal X,\mathcal F)$ is equal to the dimension of $H^i(X_0,\mathcal F|_{X_0})$ times the length of $A$ (which morally seems to me to be an analogue of "$\dim H^i(X_b,\mathcal F|_{X_b})$ is constant" in the previous paragraphe), I would like to show that  $R^i\pi_*\mathcal F$ is locally free over $B$ and satisfies the base change: $R^i\pi_*\mathcal F|_0\to H^i (X_0,\mathcal F|_0)$ is an isomorphism.

Is it possibly true ?

Comment: Maybe it is not a proper place to talk about a new question in the comment. But a parallel question is about the semi-continuity. In the same context, i.e. $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ is a family over a local artinian scheme, do we have that the length of $R^i \pi_*\mathcal F$ over $B$ is less than or equal to $\dim H^i (\mathcal X_0,\mathcal F_0)$ ?

Comment: The length condition is incorrect. At the very least, the length of $R^i\pi_*F$ should be $\dim H^i(F_{X_0})$ times the length of $A$. I have given below the best you can get.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks ! You are right ! I totally agree with you and I modified it in the question.

Comment: You haven't modified and so it is still incorrect. With my condition, what you need is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $B$ being reduced. These are originally proved by Grothendieck using the following result of his.

Let $\pi:X\to B=\operatorname{Spec}A$, $A$ Noetherian, be a proper map of finite type and $F$ a coherent sheaf on $X$, flat over $B$. Then there is a complex $P_•$ of projective modules of finite type, $0\to P_0\to P_1\to\cdots\to P_n\to 0$ over $A$ such that for any morphism $g:Y\to B$ if we denote by $p:X\times_B Y\to Y$, the pull back and $h:X\times_B Y\to X$, then $R^ip_*h^*F=H^i(g^*P_•)$.

Using this, whatever you can get is the best.